# Best practices for animating shapes under Android Canvas

Tags: android, android-animation, android-canvas, android-view

I have a custom view that draws a few circles and about 10 arches that are constantly updating (rotation and size change). I am trying to animate this whole process, but I couldn't find any good practices for doing so under Canvas (I know the basics - use dp instead of px and so on), but I don't know hot to properly do the animation part.

Right now I'm iterating trough all of my objects, perform some calculations to determine the future position and draw them, but it looks choppy. Here is what I'm currently doing:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for(Arch arch : arches) {
        arch.update();
        canvas.drawArc(arch.getRect(), -arch.getCurrentRotation(), arch.getSweepAngle(), true, paint);
    }

    //logo.draw(canvas);

    canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, circle_size, paint_opaque);

    logo.draw(canvas);

    int textX = (int) (width / 2);
    int textY = (int) ((height / 2) - ((paint_text.descent() + paint_text.ascent()) / 2));

    canvas.drawText(text, textX, textY, paint_text);
    invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few things wrong with your code.

1. You shouldn't be performing any *heavy* operations in the `onDraw` of your custom `Views`. That's one, really important principle of developing for android! Ideally inside your `onDraw` method you should ONLY draw. Sometimes you need to calculate something based on `Canvas`, but you should limit these sort of actions to the minimum. Everything you can preallocate and calculate somewhere else (not in `onDraw`), you should extract from your `onDraw`. In your case `arch.update()` (which I assume calculates the next "frame" of the animation) and calculation of your `textX` and `textY` should be moved somewhere else.
2. `invalidate()` basically means that you request for a redraw of your `View`. When a `View` is being redrawn, its `onDraw` will be called. That's why you really shouldn't be calling `invalidate()` in your `onDraw`! If every single `onDraw` requests for another `onDraw`, it causes a sort of an infinite loop to happen.
3. If you're trying to achieve a frame animation, you should be calculating all frame-related parameters in a separate thread that would wait some interval between updates, and would call `invalidate()` after every single one of them.